# What is the correct way to style canvas area is storybook

Tags: storybook

In storybook, all stories are sitting tight agains the top left corner of the container.

[image: Example of story appearance]

This is causing problems when displaying items that have visual appearance outside the relative container e.g. a box-shadow.

So I am wondering what is the best way to add margin to the surrounding container. I had a look in the theming docs of storybook, but could not find anything related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.storybook/preview.js`, you can just add the following:

```
addDecorator(storyFn => (
  <>
    <div style={{ margin: '1rem' }}>{storyFn()}</div>
  </>
))
```

This way all the stories will appear with  a margin of `1rem`.

Answer (score 2):

To globally center all stories in the UI, you can make use of the `layout` parameter.

For additional information, please refer to the [Story layout](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-layout) section.

```
<!-- Checkbox.stories.mdx -->    
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs';    
import { Checkbox } from './Checkbox';

<Meta
  title="Checkbox"
  parameters={{
    layout: 'centered',
  }}
  component={Checkbox}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my preview.js:

```
export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <div style={{ margin: '3em'}}>
      <Story />
    </div>
  )
]
```

solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

It's better to add padding on each component because not all components needs margins.
For example, in your .stories.tsx file

```
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof IconButton> = (args) => (
  <div style="padding: 20px"><YourComponent {...args} /></div>
)
```